# Dump Page table layout (KERNEL CONFIG)

Tags: linux, kernel, debugging, development

While configuring kernel for debugging found this option:

> CONFIG_X86_PTDUMP: Export kernel
>   pagetable layout to userspace via
>   debugfs

Does this mean RAM page-table layouts ? any guides on how to use debugfs and view this layout ?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069620/print-kernels-page-table-entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the following:

- [Page table management](http://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html)
- [Dumping kernel page tables](http://linux-hacks.blogspot.com/2009/08/dumping-kernel-page-tables.html)